# Paginate by date

Tags: 7, views, datetime, paging

This is for Drupal 7.

I Have a content type which includes a date field. Is there a way I can configure the view to perform the pagination based on month.

E.g page 1 => all results for current month, page 2 => all result for month before, etc...

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not directly with a pager. But you could do an exposed filter in views for the year. This will create a dropdown with the values found on the nodes.